# 'jQuery' is undefined IE8

Tags: jquery

On [my website](http://www.notable.ca/stoli), I'm getting the following error when I include `jquery.easing.1.3.js`:

```
'jQuery' is undefined. jquery.easing.1.3.js
code 0
URI: http://notable.ca/stoli/js/jquery.easing.1.3.js
line 39
char 1
```

Does anyone know what this means?

Here's how I'm including the scripts:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://notable.ca/stoli/js/onload_basic.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://notable.ca/stoli/js/widths.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://notable.ca/stoli/js/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://notable.ca/stoli/js/validation.js"></script>
```

Comment: In future, please make your question useful to future visitors by including the relevant code in your question; like I've done for you this time. On the otherhand however, that's a very nice looking site.

Comment: Sorry, will do, new at using this site and its features :)

Answer (score 3):

You need to include the jQuery library in your html BEFORE this plugin.

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://notable.ca/stoli/js/onload_basic.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://notable.ca/stoli/js/widths.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://notable.ca/stoli/js/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://notable.ca/stoli/js/validation.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You JS load order is wrong.

Jquery should be the *FIRST* one to be loaded.

Answer (score 0):

You're including jQuery *after* you're including the easing script:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://notable.ca/stoli/js/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

easing depends on jQuery, so you need to include it first.

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://notable.ca/stoli/js/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're including the plugin before you've loaded jQuery.  Move the jQuery loading to the top of your JavaScript includes.